# Using "pip download" with dependencies for multiplatform use

Tags: python, pip, pypi, multiplatform

After reading the pip download documentation page, I can't seem to find a way to download a package's truly multiplatform dependencies using pip, as the --platform tag forces the use of --only-binary=:all:

For example:

```
pip download matplotlib --platform=manylinux1_x86_64 --only-binary=:all:
```

Will download the only-binary wheels (not surprising) and will fail if only the package source is found (which will be downloaded if using just "pip download matplotlib" or when installing the package).

I'm looking for a way to download wheels if possible but if they're not found to just download the dependency's source. Downloading just the package and dependencies all in source format is also acceptable.

Does anyone know of a way to do this in pip or another software capable of such a feat ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download available Windows binaries with pip, and source for all else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48925659/how-to-download-available-windows-binaries-with-pip-and-source-for-all-else)

Comment: It is very close, however, "pip download" with no arguments prefers downloading a platform specific whl (for the downloading machine). So when removing the requirement for windows (because no windows whl exists) and a linux whl exists it willl download it and not the source.

Comment: The accepted answer says *No, according to the pip documentation, such an option does not exist*.